# jQuery each error :Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '18' in div[data-role=page]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My html is like

```
<div data-role="page" id="Dialog_1" data-url="Dialog_1">...</div>
<div data-role="page" id="Dialog_2" data-url="Dialog_2">...</div>
 .
 .
 .
<div data-role="page" id="Dialog_17" data-url="Dialog_17">...</div>
<div data-role="page" id="Dialog_18" data-url="Dialog_18">...</div>
```

i want to select all data-role="page" by the $.each

My jQuery

```
$.each("div[data-role=page]", function (){
   console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

it is giving the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '18' in div[data-role=page]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8xUy3/

Answer (score 17):

You need to supply a jQuery collection, instead of just a selector to the `$.each()`:

```
$.each($("div[data-role=page]"), function (){
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

Or, even better:

```
$("div[data-role=page]").each(function (){
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

Please note that I replaced `$(this).attr('id')` with `this.id`. It gets exactly the same property, but it's way more efficient.

**[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8xUy3/1/)**

Comment: As a further optimization, use `this.id` instead of `$(this).attr('id')`

Comment: @Blazemonger: I can't believe I overlooked that.

Answer (score 9):

The key reason your code isn't working is because you're trying to iterate a string, which isn't what you really want to do.

To iterate jQuery collections, try the other form of `.each()`:

```
$("div[data-role=page]").each(function() {
    //...
});
```

`$.each()` is (usually) for arrays or plain objects.

Answer (score -3):

An attribute value must be inside ' '

Try something like this:

```
$.each("div[data-role='page']", function (){
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: what you are trying to say is completely wrong. please refer other answers.

Comment: The attribute value can be unquoted if it's a single word: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/