# Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '42' in a Json-String

Tags: jquery, json, fullcalendar

i'm using the full calendar resource modification with jQuery 1.8.1 all the time. Now I wanted to upgrade to the newest version of jQuery but it doesn't work anymore. I think there is a problem with my Json-String. I have read something that the $.each method won't work for some arrays anymore. Here is my specific example:

```
[  
{  
  "id":79,
  "name":"Florian Sauerwein",
  "anwesenheit":[  
     {  
        "tag":1,
        "von":"08:30:00",
        "bis":"10:30:00"
     },
     {  
        "tag":2,
        "von":"09:00:00",
        "bis":"13:00:00"
     },
     {  
        "tag":3,
        "von":"11:00:00",
        "bis":"13:00:00"
     },
     {  
        "tag":0,
        "von":"09:30:00",
        "bis":"15:00:00"
     },
     {  
        "tag":4,
        "von":"00:00:00",
        "bis":"00:00:00"
     },
     {  
        "tag":5,
        "von":"00:00:00",
        "bis":"00:00:00"
     },
     {  
        "tag":6,
        "von":"00:00:00",
        "bis":"00:00:00"
     },
     {  
        "tag":7,
        "von":"00:00:00",
        "bis":"00:00:00"
     }
  ]
}
]
```

My console says: Uncaught TypeError:

```
Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '42' in pages/terminplaner/json-resources.php jquery.min.js:2 sjquery.min.js:2 n.extend.eachfullcalendar.js:1212 normalizeEventfullcalendar.js:929 (anonymous function)fullcalendar.js:997 $.ajax.$.extend.successjquery.min.js:2 n.Callbacks.jjquery.min.js:2 n.Callbacks.k.fireWithjquery.min.js:4 xjquery.min.js:4 n.ajaxTransport.k.cors.a.crossDomain.send.b
```

Here's the code from fullcalendar.js where I think there's the problem:

```
var resources = options.resources;
    $.each(
        resources,
        function(index, resource){
            if(resource.id === event.resourceId) {
                event.resource = resource;
            }
        }
    );
```

Does anyone have an idea how to get this work with the newest version of jQuery?

Comment: What's `options.resources`?

Comment: that's the url to my json-resources.php file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery each error :Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '18' in div\[data-role=page\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23632737/jquery-each-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-use-in-operator-to-search-for-1)

Comment: @FlorianSauerwein And you're iterating over your URL? I'm not convinced the code snippets represent the issue very well.

Comment: When I do a console.log(resources) it just gives me the URL to my json-resources.php . I just noticed it does nothing at all. When i just delete that $.each method, it still works and it even works with the current version of jQuery. I have no idea what that was for.