# Each function cannot use in operator using on function

Tags: jquery, each

I am missing something simple here:

The below inputs are created dynamically.  How do I use each and on, or how do i delegate the each to elements that dont exist when code is loaded?

```
 <table align='center'><tr><td>

<?php
for ($i = 1;$i<5);$i++){
 <input type='text' class='qty' id='order[qty][".$i."]' name='order[qty][".$i."]'>
 }
 ?>
```

js

```
    $('table').on('change','.qty',function(){
                    $.each('.qty',function(e,i){
                            alert(e+i);
                    });
    });
```

results in:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '3' in .qty

Comment: Why are you posting your PHP?

Comment: to show you what the .qty class is related to

Comment: Post the rendered HTML, the PHP has no relevancy in this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery each error :Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '18' in div\[data-role=page\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23632737/jquery-each-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-use-in-operator-to-search-for-1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the parameters of [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), it doesn't take a  selector as the initial argument. It takes an array or an object.

You might want this instead

```
$(".qty").each(function(i, e){
                 alert(i);
               });
```

Comment: how would i do this on dynamically created elements.  those inputs are created dynamically so I would need to use the on function..

Comment: @bart2puck, you would keep the code inside the `on` function. It's just the `$.each` statement that you're changing.